# SHA256 vs HMAC empty message

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, sha256, hmac

why those functions return different values?

```
from hashlib import sha256
import hmac

seed = "seed".encode('utf-8')

def genSHA256():
    return = sha256(seed).hexdigest()
    #19b25856e1c150ca834cffc8b59b23adbd0ec0389e58eb22b3b64768098d002b

def genHMACsha256():
    return hmac.new(seed, b"", sha256).hexdigest()
    #2ad1ced5a9ef8e90bce26c0ac9fae5af5e4b4442b2315ed58bf772a54e24fd50
```

If I put empty string in message value in the HMAC one, why does not return same as simple SHA256?
Are this two values related?

Comment: return hmac.new(seed, b"", sha256).hexdigest()
is the same as
return hmac.new(seed, None, sha256).hexdigest()

Comment: You should check the difference between `sha256` and `hmac`. [This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79577/whats-the-difference-between-hmac-sha256key-data-and-sha256key-data) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seed is masked with `ipad` and `opad` when HMAC is used, and HMAC consists of two hash iterations, even when HMAC is used over an empty string.

Basically the only way to get the same results as HMAC from a hash function is to use it to build HMAC - as the HMAC definition only uses the hash as secure primitive function.